# Using cascade Splitters and Aggregators effectively in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following xml coming in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <case>
      <issue>
         <issueid>123</issueid>
      </issue>
      <issue>

             <issueid>456</issueid>
          </issue>
       </case>
       <case>
          <issue>
             <issueid>789</issueid>
          </issue>
       </case>
    </root>
```

The summary of the xml is that each case will have multiple issues. Each issue can have one source.
 Now I have to take each issue and hit the rest service using the `<issueid>` value to retrieve the sources associated to that issue. 
 Then I have to restructure the xml in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <case>
      <issue>
         <issueid>123</issueid>
         <source>s1</source>
      </issue>
      <issue>
         <issueid>456</issueid>
         <source>s2</source>
      </issue>
   </case>
   <case>
      <issue>
         <issueid>789</issueid>
         <source>s3</source>
      </issue>
   </case>
</root>
```

What is the best way to complete the above task so that splitting cases, splitting issues, assigining the sources to the issues, aggregating all the cases and aggregating all the issues associated with the cases becomes much easier?

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear.

Spring Integration provides `XPathMessageSplitter` component which can be applied to the `//case` for the first level. The second `XPathMessageSplitter` then will have to deal with the `//issue`. The next component in the flow should be something like `XPathTransformer` to extract `//issueid` value for your service.

The backward logic is a bit tricky because there is no built-in `xml-aggregator` in Spring Integration. But you can achieve that via some custom `MessageGroupProcessor`, e.g. building output XML as String from all the messages in group.

Comment: Instead of `MessageGroupProcessor`, I have used java code to finish my task.

Comment: Well, the `MessageGroupProcessor` implementation is Java code as well. But that is good that you have figure out the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I will try to answer anyways.

Lets think of the 1st part. you can do something like below

```
<si:chain id="xmlInputchain" input-channel="xmlInputChannel"  output-channel="aggregatorChannel">   
    <si:service-activator id="xmlRequestHandler" method="xmlRequestProcessing" ref="xmlRequestService" />
    <si:splitter/>      
    <si:service-activator id="webService" method="webserviceMethod" ref="webServiceClient" />           
</si:chain>
```

This will take care of splitting each case, and in your webserviceClient, you can call the webserivce for each issue and store the info in an array and forward it to aggregatorChannel

For the 2nd part (aggregatorChannel),This Spring page has some examples about aggregation

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/aggregator.html